# Google analaytics for android displays only one type of events

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have noticed, that many people on the Internet are complaining about GA for android, but I haven't found anyone else with this specific problem:

Google analytics displays only ONE TYPE of events for me and does not show any other. By one type I mean just one specific combination of category and action as you can se on the picture below:

[image: Events]

However, my app is sending many different events with other categories and actions than just GameStats and HUMAN VS COMPUTER EASY and I can't see them in my GA account. I waited more than 3 days and the other events still didn't show up, so that's probably not the issue. I tried to run the app with GA set to debug mode and the log said, that data were sucessfuly sent.

To send events I use the EasyTracker class. Here are some snippets from my code:

EasyTracker is initialised in xml file like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In every activity I call these in start and stop methods:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); //onStart
EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); //onStop
```

And I send events like this:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("Advertisig", "Clicks", "facebookButton", 0l);
EasyTracker.getInstance().dispatch();
```

Here is log I get after sending the event above in debug mode:

```
05-30 17:16:49.100: I/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
05-30 17:16:49.100: I/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
05-30 17:16:49.135: I/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode terminated.
05-30 17:16:49.215: V/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: dispatch running...
05-30 17:16:49.225: I/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/2.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; sk-sk; GT-I9300 Build/JZO54K)
05-30 17:16:49.225: I/GAV2(17863): Host: ssl.google-analytics.com
05-30 17:16:49.225: I/GAV2(17863): GET /collect?ul=sk-sk&ev=0&ht=1369927009102&sr=720x1280&a=0&aid=numerus.gui&ea=Clicks&cid=98b46c43-714c-41f6-84a3-6761c595d55d&ec=Advertisig&av=1.1.5&v=1&t=event&el=facebookButton&an=Numerus&tid=UA-39224965-2&_u=.C&_v=ma1b5&cd=numerus.gui.MainMenuActivity&qt=131&z=243 HTTP/1.1
05-30 17:16:52.400: V/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: sent 1 of 1 hits
05-30 17:16:52.415: I/GAV2(17863): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
```

The log looks totaly OK to me. Did I forget to add something to my code? Does the EasyTracker have some limits, so I should switch to other tracker? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Nope, maybe there is a bug on the GA server side :(